# Vite injects empty array into service-worker (self.__WB_MANIFEST)

Tags: vite, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to setup precaching with VitePWA. The service worker registers fine, but VitePWA injects an empty array into the file so no assets are being cached.

I have no clue as to why that's a case and can't find any issues on google / github.

I suppose I'm configuring it wrong.

This is the vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';
import viteCompression from 'vite-plugin-compression';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
  envPrefix: 'REACT_APP_',
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html}'],
      },
      srcDir: 'src',
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      injectRegister: false,
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'module',
      },
    }),
    viteCompression(),
  ],
});
```

And this is part of the service-worker

```js
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';

self.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST); //<-- Will be inlined to []
```

How can I configure VitePWA to include all assets in the /public directory?